# Android Studio ver 2.2 preview 2, POOR TextInputEditText

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

When i Run my APP under ver 2.2 preview 1, there is no background shadow to TextInputEditText. how to solve this problem in ver 2.2 preview 2 ?

-I use **Samsung Tab4 KITKAT** to run my APP

Answer (score 1):

Some version of android plugin for gradle had a bug of handling 9.png files (see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210312&can=1&q=2.2.0-alpha1%209.png&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened) , you need to upgrade your android plugin to 2.2.0-alpha5 or higher version like this:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha6'
```